# Can I display the output of a file with extension *.php as XML in Chrome?

Tags: xml, google-chrome, xml-generation

I have a PHP script that outputs valid XML to the browser. Is there a way that I can get Chrome to display this as XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the content type in the HTTP header to state that the output is XML formatted. Put this in the top of your PHP script:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
```

Comment: Yup! The browser looks for this info first. File extension isn't actually supposed to be meaningful here.